# How to set seek bar player on lock screen ios7?

Tags: xcode, avaudioplayer

When my AVAudioPlayer is playing in background I can see the title of my song and the album's image, but I could not set the seek bar. I tried to set the MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration and the MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime but nothing appears in the lock screen, any solutions? Thanks a lot!!

UPDATE :

```
  Class playingInfoCenter = NSClassFromString(@"MPNowPlayingInfoCenter");

if (playingInfoCenter) {
  NSMutableDictionary *songInfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
  UIImage *cover=[UIImage imageNamed:@"cd.jpeg"];
  NSNumber *durationTrack= [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[self.audioPlayer getAudioDuration]];
  NSNumber *elapsedTime= [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[self.audioPlayer getCurrentAudioTime]];
  NSNumber *rate= [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[self.audioPlayer rate]];

    [songInfo setObject:@"Arbitri Elegantiae - Medley -" forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
    [songInfo setObject:cover forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork];
    [songInfo setObject:elapsedTime forKey:MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime];
    [songInfo setObject:durationTrack forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration];
    [songInfo setObject:rate forKey:MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate];
    [[MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter] setNowPlayingInfo:songInfo];
}
```

Comment: do you set MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate to 1.0f?

Comment: how did you solved this problem? i have the same problem and set the playbackRate doesn't help

Comment: Hi Jeanette, I published an update, here you can find how I solved the problem!